# I want to exclude UITableViewCell's subview from changing background when I selected it

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to exclude UITableViewCell's subview(**viewz**) from changing background when I selected it.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

UIView *viewz = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
viewz.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:viewz];
```

Cell didn't selected. Everything all right.

http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/1599/screenshot20121129at123.png

Cell has changed color to blue. It's ok. But I do not want that my **viewz** changing background color to blue. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an empty implementation of the setSelected:animated: method to your UITableViewCell subclass

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

}
```

Comment: I added [super setSelected: animated:] and viewz.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; to this method and it works.

Comment: Oh god this took me two days to figure out! Thank you so much. This is pretty annoying issue though.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to *touch* the background color or the default cell implementation will change it for you.
If you add a colored border you'll see `viewz` is still there, even if you comment the line where I change the background color:

```
#define VIEWZ_TAG 1234

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ... 
    UIView *viewz = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    viewz.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    viewz.tag = VIEWZ_TAG;
    viewz.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    viewz.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:viewz];
    ...
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([cell isSelected]) {
        UIView *viewz = [cell viewWithTag:VIEWZ_TAG];
        viewz.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
}
```

If you want fine control of the cell when it's selected you can use a custom `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

You only add the custom cell, and on select row, you change the background color of that view.